# Payment Gateway Option in France

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

Looking for a payment gateway that will work with French banks. As similar to authorize.net as possible. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find what you're looking for as International merchant accounts (e.g. outside of the US) don't work in a manner that companies like Authorize.Net can work with. Typically the merchant account provider is also the payment gateway provider. This means you can't use a third party payment gateway like Authorize.Net.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply [Paypal](http://www.paypal.fr/fr)?